# How do I run two servers off one IP address?

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, routing, reverse-proxy

I am running a web server and now I want to be able to use another device that also requires port 80, but I only have a single IP. My web server is Ubuntu and uses Apache. Is there a trick to reroute requests to a certain internal IP based on a domain name? How would I do that?

Comment: Are you wanting to run two web servers or run two websites on the same web server?

Comment: Two "servers". I have one of those NAS devices that require port 80 to be forwarded to it. I am already running multiple web sites.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) as a [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for this.

Answer (score 2):

- create apache namevirtualhosts and forward one virtualhost traffic to the internal IP address with mod_proxy (ProxyPass or RewriteRule [P] )

or

- use iptables DNAT to forward all requests coming to port 81 towards internal IP port 80.